# Trying to keep types unwrapped when using refined

Tags: scala, shapeless, refined

I am trying to use refined to create smart constructors based on primitives and avoid wrapping since same types might be used in large collections.  Am I doing this right? Seems to work but a bit boilerplaty

```
    type ONE_Pred = = MatchesRegex[W....
    type ONE = String @@ ONE_Pred
    type TWO_Pred = OneOf[...
    type TWO = String @@ TWO_PRED
```

and then

```
 case class C(one:ONE, two:TWO)
 object C {
  def apply(one:String, two:String):Either[String, C] = 
  (
   refineT[ONE_Pred](one),
   refineT[TWO_Pred](two)
  ).mapN(C.apply)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Refined` has a mechanism for creating a companion-like objects that have some utilites already defined:

```scala
type ONE = String @@ MatchesRegex["\\d+"]
object ONE extends RefinedTypeOps[ONE, String]
```

Note that:

1. You don't need a *predicate type* to be mentioned separately
2. It works for both shapeless tags and refined own newtypes. The flavor you get is based on the structure of `type ONE`.

You get:

- `ONE("literal")` as alternative to `refineMT`/`refineMV`
- `ONE.from(string)` as alternative to `refineT`/`refineV`
- `ONE.unapply` so you can do `string match { case ONE(taggedValue) => ... }`
- `ONE.unsafeFrom` for when your only option is to throw an exception.

With these "companions", it's possible to write much simpler code with no need to mention any predicate types:

```scala
object C {
  def apply(one: String, two: String): Either[String, C] =
    (ONE.from(one), TWO.from(two)).mapN(C.apply)
}
```

(example in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ge6hKm3YSYeDGWhvqKDQDA), using 2.13 with native literal types)